# ServiceStack RedisPubSubServer will enter in OnStop, OnInit, and OnStart frequently

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

Here is my situation:

1. I instantiate a RedisPubSubServer and configure it with OnInit, OnStart, and OnStop callbacks.
2. I keep this reference as long as the application lives and, in the end, I dispose it.

Somehow, during the application life cycle, I noticed that the OnStart/OnStop callbacks are called without any explicit disposing of the RedisPubSubServer, and I suspect that something goes wrong with the connection, but I cannot figure why.

Is there any way of identifying the problem? Or am I am not understanding it right how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a connection error or failover the `RedisPubSubServer` will auto-reconnect, you can get notified when this happens by overriding the `OnError` and `OnFailover` callbacks.